# Action on complete circuit via DIY USB button

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb

So I want to make a button that will be able to trigger an action on my PC.
The idea is to have a couple buttons in my room (and one outside as a doorbell) that will trigger actions on my desktop, such as execute scripts and run programs.

I want to DIY this, so the underlying question is: How can I make windows recognise when I have pressed the buttons and then complete a task?

**Note:**

I'm somewhat confident in programming (my niche is web development, but I'm okay in other areas), so will be able to do the software side once pointed in the right direction, however HW wise I have no clue how to get windows to react.

Comment: I also want to add that I am unsure if this is the right Stack Exchange site to post this on, If it is not, please educate me on which would be more suitable so I can post it there. Thank you.

Comment: Why not just [buy one](http://usbbuttons.com/)? "Our USB Buttons send a keystroke just like a USB keyboard would"

Comment: @DavidPostill Suggestion taken nicely. I will definitely look into doing that if I can't find a way to DIY it. The only reason I haven't yet looked into off-the-shelf versions, is because the satisfaction of making it myself is rather appealing.

Comment: You could also consider generating different tones from each button (as a telephone keypad does) and feeding these into your audio line input.

Comment: @DavidPostill, this is a good find! The StackExchange has numerous requests for how to make an input from USB, or toggle a bit. Most suggestions came to use of sideband GPIO on some FTDI or Cypress or Microchip USB-to-serial bridges, but this website pops up first time. Thanks. [prices, however, are horribly high!]

Comment: @AFH That is something I might have to look into, feels a bit "hacky", but if it works it works. Thanks buddy

Comment: I was trying to think of something that you can build yourself, given that you didn't want to buy an off-the-shelf USB device. If you have a parallel interface, you could look at raising input signal lines (including the RS232C status lines on a serial interface).

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways how to make a USB button. You can get a reference design for high-tech touch-sensitive buttons, from Silicon Labs, Cypress, or Microchip, it is very fashionable.

If you go for old mechanical style, many USB-to-serial bridges on the market (USB to UART, SPI, or I2C) frequently have additional GPIOs (both input and outputs), with all tools (software and hardware demo modules) available. I recently run over a [MCP2200 demo board](http://www.microchip.com/Developmenttools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=ADM00419), take a look at their package.